# EDSDK : Error if open camera session, wait some seconds and take a picture

Tags: c++, edsdk

I use EDSDK to control a canon EOS 1200D.

I try this code :

> ```
> err = EdsOpenSession(_camera);
> if(err != EDS_ERR_OK)
>     std::cout << "[ERROR] : EdsOpenSession" << std::endl;
> QThread::sleep(5);
> err = EdsSetObjectEventHandler(_camera, kEdsObjectEvent_All, handleObjectEvent, (EdsVoid*)&_path);
> if(err != EDS_ERR_OK)
>     std::cout << "[ERROR] : EdsSetObjectEventHandler" << std::endl;    
> EdsInt32 saveTarget = kEdsSaveTo_Host;
> err = EdsSetPropertyData(_camera, kEdsPropID_SaveTo, 0, 4, &saveTarget);
> if(err != EDS_ERR_OK)
>     std::cout << "[ERROR] : EdsSetPropertyData kEdsSaveTo_Host" << std::endl;
> EdsCapacity newCapacity = {0x7FFFFFFF, 0x1000, 1};
> err = EdsSetCapacity(_camera, newCapacity);
> if(err != EDS_ERR_OK)
>     std::cout << "[ERROR] : EdsSetPropertyData newCapacity" << std::endl;
> err = EdsSendCommand(_camera, kEdsCameraCommand_TakePicture, 0);
> if(err != EDS_ERR_OK)
>     std::cout << "[ERROR] : takePicture " << err << std::endl;
> ```

With the sleep I get the error `EDS_ERR_TAKE_PICTURE_CARD_NG 0x00008D07L` when I do `EdsSendCommand(_camera, kEdsCameraCommand_TakePicture, 0)`.
Without the sleep, all works well.

Does the camera session has a timeout ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in C # . I solved the problem by using a Timer component to run the rest of the code . I think the EDSDK not very fond of Threads.

If you are compiling for windows can use the SetTimer function .

The link talks about the function.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I hope you can solve your problem.